# How exactly will the lifespan of my laptop computer decrease if I chose to remove the fan, for silence?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I would like to know what will happen in terms of negative effects if I remove the fan from my ULV-CPU (intel core i7-5600U) powered Thinkpad Laptop (T450s) which is running under ubuntu linux at the moment. Reason being, I really can't stand fan noise (or rather the fan spinning up every once in a while and moving my attention to it). And I would certainly accept a performance penalty to get it more quiet. What would be great is a hardware switch to switch off the fan, and switch it on on demand. But this seems to be not in the scope of any manufacturer :'(.

The CPU has a thermal design power of 15 Watts.

I guess it would basically get warmer than usual at office tasks, and start reducing CPU clock on high loads to avoid crossing certain temperature thresholds (I believe 90°C is set somewhere, and 100°C is hardware set).

My question now is: Given I run the laptop only passively cooled by heat conduction through the chassis and dissipation into the surrounding air, without use of a fan, such that the mean temperature of the CPU and its vicinity would lie some 10s of degrees higher than if I used the fan; would this severely affect the lifetime of the computer? By how much? I might be fine, as I'm normally not doing CPU intensive things, just browsing or writing texts. Just sometimes watching some videos, or compiling a LaTeX file.

What would be the mechanism by which the computer will most likely fail, or rather which is the mechanism that will reduce the lifetime most compared to the kept-cooler case? Is it electrolytic capacitors drying out quicker? I would be very happy for any educated insights here, as there is a lot of "oh yeah heat is sooo bad for your computer"-kind of superficial advice all over the internet. As long as there is heat dissipated in charging FET gates in the chips, we'll have this tradeoff I suppose... thanks for your advice!

EDIT: I have been using Thinkpad Laptops with ULV CPUs without active cooling (fan removed) successfully for a while, but am wondering about the effects on the lifespan. I am aware that this question is a very hardware/physicsy question.

EDIT: Judging from the mixed responses, I thought, can this question be moved to a different stackexchange, e.g. electronics? How do I do this?

EDIT: Although I felt quite offended by some of the replies, I post here in case anyone in the future will be interested in researching this further: I found this study http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf , which reports that for disk drives temperature does not seem to correlate strongly with failure rate for the temperature range the authors tested.

In this https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c354/7358d8fa3502fc09140598985d94afc4354a.pdf  technical study, the author suggests that the main problem how high temperatures can make electronic circuits fail is stresses induced by difference in the coefficients of thermal expansion, which eventually can lead to stress induced rupture, e.g. of solder joints.

Comment: You can either accept the advise in the answer below by @Tetsujin or you can do your own thing, and just remove the fan. The system will likely refuse to boot without a fan, due to safety checks. Other problems include the CPU malfunctioning due to overheating, GFX chips overheating, ram chips overheating, ssd/hdd failing due to overheating. Your fan coming on, means your fan is *required*. What you could try is to see if you can run the CPU at a lower clock speed generally, but that isn't what you've asked in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Modern laptop computers (at least the thinkpad series) have temperature sensors built in which are used by the firmware to dynamically reduce the CPU clock rate, in order to avoid crossing certain temperatures.

Comment: Every modern laptop processor has built-in temperature sensors. If the temperature is too high, it will automatically reduce clock frequency. If that's not enough, it'll automatically shut down to prevent damage.

Comment: Have you considered a compromise - reducing the fan speed so it spins quietly and still moves air?

Comment: I retract my earlier comments.  The lifespan of your laptop will be exactly 1024.731 days shorter.  Whenever it eventually dies, you can be confident that it would have lasted exactly that many days longer if you had left in the fan.

Answer (score 3):

It will likely reach thermal shutdown in about the time it takes to boot to the desktop.

If it gets as far as launching your first app, it will throttle back so far you'll wish you were using an abacus or chalkboard.

If they could run without active cooling... they would.
Just because you can't normally hear the fans doesn't mean they're not running at all.

*Edit:*
As you seem to be insistent on the lifespan issue...
No-one can say with any certainty, because no-one will ever have tested how the heat will dissipate in a fanless laptop of that precise design. All anyone can say is it will suffer from terrible performance, or it will melt something, or both.
There is no doubt the stresses will shorten its life.

Comment: This is definitely not the case. In idle the CPU doesn't consume more than an estimated 1-3 Watts. There is tablet computers without fans powering 5-10 Watt CPUs.

Comment: There are more powerful desktop computers which are completely fanless too. That doesn't change what I wrote. If they could have made your laptop fanless... they would have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think you are missing the point of the question. If you have a suggestion for clarification please let me know.

Comment: Try it & let us know how you get on.

Comment: I m new to this community. I guess I could have asked this question also on physics.stackexchange, but I thought it's more a computer hardware specific question.

Comment: @GeorgE. The *only* problem is that your device is not designed for fanless operation. It is built with the assumption that a fan removes the heated air. Also, when booting, the CPU most certainly is not idle.

Comment: Yes, on bootup the CPU isn't idle at all, agreed, but the heat capacity of the hole chassis makes it stay well away from overheating. The question is about the actual consequences when operating the device outside its design spec (which includes a fan).

Comment: Heat will not be transferred to the chassis at anything like the rate it would need to aid cooling. You will be generating a massive hot-spot right where one is least welcome... your CPU. It's like the difference between waiting for a tungsten light bulb to heat your room, vs removing it from its socket with your bare hand whilst it's lit.

Comment: Well, yes and no. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation

Comment: There is no lifespan concerns because you will be unable to use the device at all, without active cooling for the CPU.  As this answer indicates, the CPU will overheat, before the OS even boots.

Comment: This is plain wrong - I'm currently writing this on a Thinkpad with fan removed. I guess this question is asking a bit too much of the superuser community, as it requires in depth knowledge of hardware/solid state physics/electronics components engineering.

Comment: I give up. You continue to think what you want to think. I'm done. Just because you got away with it so far & are insisting there is some deep researched model already describing the effect of how much shorter the life-span might be on your precise model...

Comment: @GeorgE., nobody can give you any kind of factual or definitive answer, regardless of what site you post the question on.  There are endless variables that would make any good answer out of scope.  This is as good an answer as you will get unless you hire an electrical engineer to write a dissertation for you, covering all of the design principles they learned and researching and summarizing whatever specific test data is available.

Comment: Summary: Not liking the answer you get does not make that answer wrong. It may be imprecise, as is the input question, but it is not wrong.